# Inheriting mapping annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, jpa

I'm working on a JPA project in which I have some different Entities extending a super-class annotated as `Entity`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "export_profiles")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "ExportProfile.getAll", query = "select ep from PersistentExportProfile ep"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "ExportProfile.getByName", query = "select ep from PersistentExportProfile ep where ep.profileName = :name") })
public abstract class PersistentExportProfile extends AbstractExportProfile {

    // other mappings...

}
```

I'd like to inherit mappings defined in my `PersistentExportProfile` into each sub-class.
Is it possible? What do I have to change in my super-class, and what do I have to add in my sub-entities?

**NOTE** all the sub-classes will be mapped on the same table.

Comment: You dont need to change anything. just make your sub-classes Entities. By default the table mapping is set to single table for the entire hierarchy

Comment: @JBNizet If you don't have the patience to answer my "stupid" question you can just ignore it instead of get angry... thanks anyway ;)

Comment: I'm not angry, and I've never said your question was stupid. But this question is obviously answered in the documentation, and this documentation is easy to find. So I reiterate my question, which is a real one: why don't you read it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution for me was to add `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)` and `@DiscriminatorColumn(name="export_type", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)` to my abstract class, then in my concrete classes I added `@DiscriminatorValue` to define the value of the `DiscriminatorColumn`.

Answer (score 0):

If the sole purpose of your superclass is to define common mappings for the sub classes, but is not persistent itself, you would be better off using the `@MappedSuperclass` annotation or the `<mapped-superclass>` for xml mappings. There is an example [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html).

Answer (score 0):

This case may be a good start in Postgres.

By example

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."abstract_export_profile" (
"label" TEXT
) WITHOUT OIDS;

CREATE TABLE "public"."persistent_export_profile" (
"id" BIGSERIAL, 
"value" TEXT, 
CONSTRAINT "mandant_pkey" PRIMARY KEY("id")
) INHERITS ("public"."abstract_export_profile")
WITHOUT OIDS;
```

The Name Class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class AbstractExportProfile { ... }
```

And the

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "mandant")
public class PersistentExportProfile extends AbstractExportProfile { ... }
```

Comment: The SQL is not part of my answer, i just like the way postgres inherit.